# Какие буквы пропущены?

Tags: орфография, морфология, старая-грамматика

Ещё интересный вопрос из олимпиады:

> Перед вами — цитата из пьесы Тирсо де Молины «Севильский озорник, или
>   Каменный гость» в переводе Ю. Корнеева:
>
> В полумиле с небольшим
>
> От столицы португальской
>
> Расположен древний Белен,
>
> Монастырь, где проживает
>
> Братья, чтящ__ святого…
>
> Какие буквы мы пропустили?  (-ие , -его, -ее,
>    -ая, -ия)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая наводит на мысль, что мы имеем причастный оборот, связанный с существительным *братья*. В каком числe и роде поставить причастие? В том же, что и *братья*. "Проживает братья", следовательно *братья* — это существительное ж. р. в ед. ч. Вывод:  "братья, **чтящая**..."

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **Братья (братия), чтящая святого…**

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/750458

БРА́ТИЯ и БРАТЬЯ, братии, род. мн. братий, жен., собир. Монашеская община одного монастыря (церк.). «Шатался по разным обителям, наконец пришел к моей чудовской братии.» Пушкин.
|| перен. Лица одного круга, одной профессии (с оттенком иронии или шутки и без него). Нищая братия. Актерская братия. Пишущая братия (литераторы).

Comment: А на олимпиаде словари доступны?

Comment: Вы у меня спрашиваете?  Я не знаю. Но вот выражение "нищая братия", как мне кажется, продвинутые "олимпийцы" должны знать.