# Согласование в числе и роде: "братия" + глагол

Tags: этимология

*Братия* требует после себя глагола во множественном или в единственном числе?

Comment: Недавно был [вопрос на эту тему](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447894/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b).

Answer (score 1):

В единственном. Подобия: пролетела стая птиц, промчался табун лошадей, залаяла свора собак, молодёжь нынче обнаглела... Вся братия на трапезу собралась. Если сюда добавить прилагательное, к примеру, моностырская, оно так же будет единственного числа. Это собирательное существительное единственного числа, женского рода.

Answer (score 0):

БРА́ТИЯ - ед. ч. жен. р.

> [БРА́ТИЯ и БРАТЬЯ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/750458), братии, род. мн. братий, жен., собир. Монашеская община одного монастыря (церк.). «Шатался по разным обителям, наконец пришел к моей чудовской братии.» Пушкин. || перен. Лица одного круга, одной профессии (с оттенком иронии или шутки и без него). Нищая братия. Актерская братия. Пишущая братия (литераторы).